# Data transfer between `gz::sim::System` plugins

Tags: gazebo, gz-sim

Afaik there are two standard ways of getting data from one `gz::sim::System` to another:

1. Using Components: one system writes data into a component of an entity, the other system reads it from the component,
2. Using `gz-transport`: one system publishes messages, the other system subscribes.

**Question 1:** Are there other (better?) ways?

**Question 2:** I would like to understand better the timing:

For case 1:

I don't think the systems have write access to the components in their `PostUpdate()` step, so they need to write their data during the `PreUpdate()` step. But there is no guarantee which system will run first, so it could as well be that the receiving system is run first, and hence gets the data with one simulation iteration delay?

And for case 2:

In general, [a mutex lock is needed](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/579013fe2841de68c0901192780ab8ee86cc9bb1/src/systems/joint_controller/JointController.cc#L369-L378) to guard concurrent access to variables:

- From the subscription callback, and
- From the system itself during its `PreUpdate()`, `Update()` and `PostUpdate()`.

But in case of data transfer between systems: is the lock also required, given they don't run concurrently (except for their `PostUpdate()`)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Internally those are the 2 options that gazebo provides.
2. The order in which the system's updates are called is (currently) determined by the order that they are specified in the SDF.

> But in case of data transfer between systems: is the lock also required, given they don't run concurrently (except for their PostUpdate())?

Do you mean when setting and accessing data through components? No locks are needed as `PreUpdate` and `Update` are called one after another. Components should be readonly in `PostUpdate` so you also don't need to lock.

One thing to be aware of is that if you have a system that is a gui plugin (like the ones in [src/gui/plugins](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/src/gui/plugins)), changes done to the `EntityComponentManager` are not propagated to the server side. The gui plugins only read data from components and any requests to update entity properties are done via gz-transport.

Comment: You could also use [Events](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/namespacegz_1_1sim_1_1events.html)

Comment: @iche033 "Do you mean when setting and accessing data through components?" No, I meant the case where one system publishes messages and another subscribes. E.g. if the publishing system publishes in its `PostUpdate` step, is the message callback then synchronuous (i.e. guaranteed before the `PreUpdate` of the subscribing system), or is it asynchronuous and could the message callback happen anytime, possibly preempting the subscribing system's `PreUpdate`?

Comment: I believe it's asynchronous. The transport node manages a pub queue and msgs are published in a [separate thread](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/blob/gz-transport12/src/NodeShared.cc#L1863). For local subscribers in the same process, it's a quick callback but it's still not synchronous so no guarantee that it's going to arrive before `PreUpdate`.